# Differentiable function and increasing and decreasing problem

Tags: calculus, functions

I dont get why $\text{(I)}$ is not correct. The slope at $x=3$ is positive, meaning that $f'(x)>0$. Can anyone explain? Correct answer is $\text{(C)}$.

---

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline \;\;\;\;\;x\;\;\;\;\; & \;\;\;\;\;0\;\;\;\;\;\ & \;\;\;\;\;2\;\;\;\;\;\ & \;\;\;\;\;4\;\;\;\;\;\ & \;\;\;\;\;8\;\;\;\;\;\ \\
\hline f(x) & 3 & 4 & 9 & 13\\
\hline f'(x) & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2\\  \hline \end{array}
The table above gives values of a differentiable function $f$ and its derivative at selected values of $x$. If $h$ is the function given by $h(x)=f(2x)$, which of the following statements must be true?

$\text{(I)}$ $h$ is increasing on $2\lt x \lt4$
$\text{(II)}$ There exists $c$, where $0\lt c\lt4$, such that $h(c)=12$.
$\text{(III)}$ There exists $c$, where $0\lt c\lt2$, such that $h'(c)=3$.

$\text{(A)}$ $\text{II}$ only
$\text{(B)}$ $\text{I}$ and $\text{III}$ only
$\text{(C)}$ $\text{II}$ and $\text{III}$ only
$\text{(D)}$ $\text{I}$, $\text{II}$, and $\text{III}$

Comment: Please don't post a link like this. It is better to rewrite the question, as link can become invalid over time. You should also use MathJax to have more readable equations, you can find some help about it at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't deduce the positivity on an interval from the positivity at a single point.

Comment: so theres no way to tell if the function went down at 3?

Comment: You know the values at a finite number of points. In general you can't say anything on the whole domain.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $h(0) = 3$
 and $h(4)=4$ and you know
that $h'(0)=0$ and $h'(4)=1$.

You have no information
about  $h(x)$ or $h'(x)$ for $2<x<4$ and
therefore you cant say that
$h$ is increasing on $2<x<4$
must be true.

And nothing from from II contradicts that.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

$$f(2.1)=4.1$$

$$f (3.9) = 8.9$$

which are  not in contrast with $$f’(2)=f’(4)=1$$

but

$$f(3) =-1000$$

thus $\text{(I)}$ is not true in general.